# Is HIPE with RabbitMQ production ready?

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, hipe

does anyone enabled HIPE on RabbitMQ on production servers, if yes, did you face any problems beside the Rabbimq start-up time ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `HIPE` there are different opinions, someone uses `HIPE` without problems, but I'd be careful with it.

My suggestion is to test a lot in your environment before put it in production (Especially for mission critical applications).

You should use Erlang versions >= 19.2 because of (https://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-205).

RabbitMQ can be tuned in different ways, and I'd start form there.

Answer (score 1):

HIPE has become more stable over the years and recent versions. Now I use it in production without any segmentation fault and an important performance boost. I am using the latest version:

RabbitMQ 3.6.10, Erlang 19.2.1

You can turn it on safely, but better use the last version you can.

Answer (score 1):

[HiPE support has been dropped in Erlang 22](https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html#hipe). On 3.8.4 it is still possible to run it on Erlang 21.3.